# Need a simple answer about Queues in Java

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

I'm trying to use an ArrayBlockingQueue but I cant seem to get the syntax right and I dont know what exactly I'm supposed to import to use it.  I tried this:

```
BlockingQueue<int> Queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<int>(100);
```

for the declaration but it says that there is an error with int "Dimensions expected after this token" for both of the ints.  I feel like this is probably simple to solve, I may have just not imported to correct thing or my syntax is off, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BlockingQueue<int>
```

Java Generics do not cover primitive types. You'll have to use `Integer` instances.

This is an artifact of the *type erasure* approach taken by Java. You cannot erase an `int` to an `Object` and the actual bytecode needed to work with an `int` is entirely different. That would only be possible if C++ approach was used to instantiate the template for each type parameter separately, as a new class with new bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use atomic types as   as the element it needs to be an object, try Integer.

```
BlockingQueue<Integer> Queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>();
```